# Python relative __import__

Tags: python, import

Suppose I have a module package containing the following files. An empty file `C:\codes\package\__init__.py` and some non-trivial files:

One located in `C:\codes\package\first.py`

```
def f():
    print 'a'
```

Another located in `C:\codes\package\second.py`

```
def f():
    print 'b'
```

There is also a third file: `C:\codes\package\general.py` with the following code

```
def myPrint(module_name):
    module = __import__(module_name)
    module.f()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myPrint('first')
    myPrint('second')
```

When I run the latter file, everything goes fine. However, if I try to execute the file `C:\codes\test.py` containing

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from package import general
    general.myPrint('first')
    general.myPrint('second')
```

I get the import error `ImportError: No module named first`. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17344561/python-perform-relative-import-when-using-import

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I suspect you forgot to metion you have a (possibly empty) file `package\__init__.py` which makes `package` a package. Otherwise, `from package import general` wouldn't work.

The second case differs from the first in so far as you are in a package. From inside a package, you wouldn't do `import first`, but `import .first`. The equivalent to the latter is described [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) where you either add `level=1` as a parameter or (but I am not sure about that) you put `.first` into the string and set `level` to `-1` (if it isn't the default nevertheless, that's not clear from the documentation).

Additionally, you have to provide at least `globals()`, so the right line is

```
module = __import__(module_name, globals(), level=1)
```

I have found this solution [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue13912#msg152354).

Comment: I don't think OP forgot to add `__init__.py ` because `from package import general ` works for him

Comment: As I said: he just forgot to mention the file.

Comment: @Daniil: as glglgl rightfully noticed, indeed I've added it but forgot to mention.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so in __import__ I shall do `__import('.' + moduleName)`?

Comment: @Ulysses Try it - but probably `__import__(modulename, level=1)` will work better.

Comment: The '.' solution returns `ValueError: Empty module name`. The solution `__import__('first', level = 1)` did not work - same error as in the OP. Although I have not tried it exactly in the described setting, so my `package` folder is quite far away (I can still import `general.py` and anything inside it with no issues, so only relative import issues).

Comment: To be honest, even if I implement the whole setting as described, I can't make it work even from `general.py`

Comment: More to that, even if I just try to do `import .first` I get syntax error. I did put `from __future__ import absolute_import` since I'm using Python 2.6

Comment: @Ulysses Ok, but `absolute_import` shouldn't affect the `__import__()` function's behaviour... I'll work more on that.

Comment: @Ulysses I just updated my answer - this way I got it work under 2.7 and I hope it works under 2.6 as well.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it - but now I can't even import `package` at all. That's pretty strange. I'll try to make it work, and then get back

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you should import your `module_name` from `package`. Use `fromlist` argument:

```
getattr(__import__("package", fromlist=[module_name]), module_name)
```

Comment: And if someone renames the package? Better would be to do a relative import.

Comment: @glglgl I am not sure that it's possible to use relative pathes in `__import__`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you're using Python 3, that's just because this version dropped the support for [implicit relative imports](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PortingPythonToPy3k#relative-imports). With Python 2 it would be working just fine.

So either you'd need to use relative imports in `C:\codes\package\general.py`, which would result in erroneous call to it, or add your package to the path. A little dirty, but working hack would be:

```
def myPrint(module_name):
    pkg = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    sys.path.insert(0, pkg)
    try:
        module = __import__(module_name)
    except:
        raise
    finally:
        sys.path.remove(pkg)
    module.f()
```

Maybe you can achieve a cleaner implementation with the [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) module.